# Changes in keyboard layout. Is that per user or globally?

Tags: centos, keyboard-layout, redhat-enterprise-linux

We work with international teams.
So we have **RHEL servers** with multiple keyboard layouts.
If I change the layout of my keyboard, does this changes for other users on the same server aswell?
If so is there a was to limit this. So that certain users have keyboard x and some keyboard y.
Its very frustrating to login.

Usually use something like this : **localectl set-locale LANG=en_GB.utf8**

As an example.
But even then the login window will we wrong.

Comment: `localectl` will set locale for all users. To change for only your user, you can add `LANG="en_GB.utf8"; export LANG` in your user's `~\.bash_profile` for example